# The bearers don't have the meaning of soldiers in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

The following is from The African Queen by C. S. Forester

> ... not that Von Hanneken and his troops had descended upon the place
>   and had swept off the entire village, convert and heathen alike, to be
>   soldiers or **bearers** in the Army of German Central Africa, which he
>   was assembling.

I looked up the word '[bearer](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bearer?q=bearer)' and googled, which produced 'standard bearer' and 'stretcher bearer' for the military. They wear uniforms and they are soldiers, part of an army and doing different duties. The bearers don't have the meaning of soldiers in this context?

Comment: Just a guess, in those days a standard bearer would accompany a group of soldiers, to show their colours. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard-bearer) says "soldier or civilian".

Comment: @ Weather Vane: There also appears to be a stretcher-bearer, a kind of medic. So these bearers are not soldiers like fighters but more like supporting units? Is this the reason the author made a distinction between soldiers and bearers?

Comment: Yes, that is why they may be civilians - in wars when there was mass volunteering or conscription, people who might object to being a fighter (because of having to kill others) sometimes volunteered for necessary duties that might be just as dangerous, because they were not actually cowards.

Comment: -1 which dictionaries did you check, which definitions did you consider, why did they not work for you? You are expected to do *some* research before asking a question. Also, see [details please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *bearer* was a servant who (originally) carried (bore) things from place to place. It comes from this definition (source: dictionary.com):

> 1. a person or thing that carries, upholds, or brings

In some contexts it acquired a more general meaning:

> 6. (especially in India) a native boy or man employed as a personal or household servant.

In the context of a 19th-century European army in Africa, it almost certainly meant local people hired or conscripted to work as servants for the army or the army officers. It might even have meant servants who literally carried the army's equipment on the march, in which case they might also be called *porters*.

As mentioned in the comments, in a military context this word is nowadays more often used to designate people who carry very specific burdens, for example *standard-bearers* or *stretcher bearers*.

Comment: In the context of colonial Africa, "bearers" was specifically used to designate native people who carried baggage and supplies into remote areas. Much of the terrain was unsuitable for wheeled or even animal transport. For some reason, "porters" was not a term generally used in the context of English-speaking colonial Africa. "Bearer" may be a loan word from Afrikaans.

Comment: @JeffMorrow, that's what I would have thought too, but I couldn't find a reference to back it up. The one I cited is the closest I found. Do you have a reference that gives the meaning for African context?

Comment: @photon I do not have an authoritative reference. I have looked up "native bearer" on Google ngram. The phrase suddenly appears in the 1850's (Burton and Speke?) as African exploration heated up. It then varied in frequency of usage and has dwindled remarkably since about 1960. So ngram is consistent with a colonialist usage, but hardly dispositive. I read a wealth of late nineteenth and early twentieth century boys' novels as a child, and that experience may have made me an authority on the literature of imperialism.